# Checking if two objects are equal even if they could be null

Tags: java, null

Sometimes, I see this:

```
if (a.equals(b)) do(something);
```

However, if `a` is null, a NullPointerException is thrown.  Assuming when `a==null` and `b==null` or if just `a==b` that I would want to `do(something)`.  What's the simplest way to do this check without getting an exception?

Comment: Handling null as a special case? It seems such a trivial solution that I assume there's a reason you can't do that? Please elaborate.

Comment: This seems so trivial doesn't it?  It appears to have stumped two others.  This would make an interesting interview question.  It's not that's hard, but that it's hard to do in a simple way.

Comment: Sometimes the things that look simple are not always the easiest to accomplish.  This was the first lesson I learned in calculus, and looking for the catch in anything has saved me from ALOT of missteps

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to compare the object or if the two a and b are pointing to same object?
for first option the answers just if(a==b)
for second option its if(a==b && a==null||a.equals(b) )

Comment: Just as equals() always works, compare the object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
if( a==b || (a!=null && a.equals(b)) )
```

(The `a==b` handles the case when both are null.)

---

Also be aware of the Java 7 and above [Object.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
if(java.util.Object.equals(a, b))
```

Comment: +1, this is pretty much what various .equals() utility methods do, too.  For example: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Since not all equals() methods contain the "if (o == this) return true" optimization, I think this formulation is the clear winner, and is what I used in Guava's Objects.equal() method.

Comment: Very good answer. Just one note: in your answer, **Object** should be **Objects**

Answer (score 24):

Another way of writing it.

```
if (a == null ? b == null : a.equals(b))
```

Comment: @Steve - that is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Stephen C  ,and the opinion seems to win majority
+1 more readable and seems good

Comment: The problem with this version is that it completely ignores the a == b case which could save a lot of calculation for some some objects.

Comment: Or it could be a premature optimisation as equals should have this and it might be inlined. ;)